# How to read the status code of Okhttp response in android

Tags: android, okhttp

### My Current code:

```
public static InputStream postRequestWithPayload(String url, String mJsonReq) throws Exception {
         Response response;
         try{
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, mJsonReq);
            client.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
            client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader(AppConstants.OKHTTP_HEADER_GENERAL_USERNAME, AppController.getUserName())
                    .addHeader(AppConstants.OKHTTP_HEADER_GENERAL_AUTHTOLKEN, AppController.getToken().toString())
                            //.addHeader(AppConstants.OKHTTP_HEADER_GENERAL_APP_IDENTIFIER, AppConstants.OKHTTP_HEADER_GENERAL_APP_IDENTIFIER_VALUE)
                    .build();
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
         }
         return response.body().byteStream();
     }
```

### What i am trying to do:

1. I am trying to read the status code of the response
2. How to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `response.code()`. From the documentation

> /** Returns the HTTP status code. */

Answer (score 2):

Use method *code()* of Response object:

```
response.code();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpResponse` class and using that you can access the status code as follows;

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

If you are using `com.squareup.okhttp.Response` then you can use the `code()` method to get the HTTP status code.

```
Response httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
httpResponse.code();
```

Answer (score 1):

you might also be interested in `response.isSuccessful()` method
which returns true if code is in **[200..300)**